# LaTeX: Automatic two-column wrapping of content

Tags: latex

Say I have a list of words that need to retain their order, and need to be sorted into two columns.

I can do this rather well with a tabular:

```
\begin{tabular}{l l}
abc & def \\
ghi & jkl \\
\end{tabular}
```

But doing so makes it rather difficult and time consuming to reorder the list.

Is it possible to have an automatically wrapped two-column list?
Ideally, I would like to simply enter an ordered list:

```
\begin{magic}
abc \\
def \\
ghi \\
jkl \\
\end{magic}
```

And have it wrapped to two columns (as the tabular enables):

```
abc  def
ghi  jkl
```

Comment: Do you need this to wrap across multiple pages (and, if so, how should it wrap?), or is this something that's guaranteed to fit on a single page?

Comment: It could get rather large - I'm going to use it for Koine Greek vocabulary (which will contain the word and its definition).
So, yes, I need it to wrap across multiple pages.

EDIT: On second thought, though, I envision that ordering to be more difficult to use than right to left ordering..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second attempt, tested:

```
\def\word{\let\word\rightword \message{First}}
\def\leftword{\\ \let\word\rightword \message{Left}}
\def\rightword{\> \let\word\leftword \message{Right}}
\begin{tabbing}
\hskip 3in \=\\
% Items
\word One
\word Two
\word Three
\end{tabbing}
```

This version is indeed ugly.  A negative vskip after the `\\` in the tabbing env would be a good thing.  This can be adapted to use the `\\`s in your 'magic' environment.

Comment: I can't get this to work. Here's the error with the original: http://latex.pastebin.com/DuE4tpQc
And here's my edited version and the errors that come with it: http://latex.pastebin.com/NVABkQTc

Comment: Hmm. This has issues with long words/definitions. It seems each item needs to be encased in another box or something to do wrapping.. Though it still works rather well and I can change the definitions to fit it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the multicol environment. Not sure if this is what you want, but

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{itemize}
\item abc
\item def
% etc
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
```

will wrap the list into two cols. You need to `\usepackage{multicol}` i think, but it might be `multicols`. I should also note that you can use `\begin{multicols*}{2}` to create similar environment, but with a different property: `\begin{multicols}` creates columns and balances them equally, but `\begin{multicols*}` creates columns and fills the first before going to the second (so won't always be 'balanced', which is more ideal for papers).

Comment: This works well(ish) for the original ordering (which I changed to right-to-left).
Do you know if there's a way to remove the bullet points (without doing '\item[] blah' every time) and the whitespace surrounding the items? Or how to order them right-to-left instead of top-bottom?

Comment: @plash: You can eliminate the bullet using `\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\hskip-1em}` (adjust dim to your taste).

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off with creating the table in some other program and using a script or export function to convert it to a LaTeX table. The `longtable` package will allow that table to wrap across multiple pages.

Comment: I don't like the idea of having to run a script every time I add a new item to the list.
Also, the idea here is ease of addition and reordering. It's tedious to do either with tables.